# Lazy Loading in GridView in UWP C# in a slightly different way

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm utilizing an API which returns a list of image URLs. But the problem with the API is it only provides 50 URLs per page, for the second page, we want to make a request with the `page` parameter in the API.

```
https://api.someservice.com/images?page=2
```

Now, my doubt is I want to implement a lazy loading GridView and when the GridView reaches it's end, it want to request the API with the next page number and populate the second page results along with first page results in an `ObservableCollection`. How can I do that??

I'm using .NET5 with `System.Net.Http` for API requests.

I you guys have any idea, please help me ...

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a look at [Incremental Loading Collection Helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/helpers/incrementalloadingcollection). It simplifies the definition and usage of collections whose items can be loaded incrementally only when needed by the view.